# Storing Image Bytes into database not working

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, arrays, byte

Hello everyone I am making a simple web application that utilizes the users webcam and/or allows you to  upload pictures. Please ignore the error in the images, it's done on purpose.

I get the Bytes of the Image like this:

[image]

Now I want to enter it into my Database with the SQL data type Image. 
In my data access layer I have parameters that look like this:

[image].

```
  public int AddParam(string ParamName, byte[] pic)
    {
        return AddParam( ParamName, pic);

    }
```

I entered them and tried to execute it like this:

[image]

```
 DataAccessLayer DataAccessLayer = new DataAccessLayer()    
 DataAccessLayer.PictureCaptured(dlStudentID.SelectedValue.ToString(),imgByte.ToArray());
                                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                                DataAccessLayer .WebExecute(out ds);
```

It gives me an error like this:[image]

I don't understand why it is doing that.

Please let me know if you have any tips or answers to it.

Thank You very much.

Comment: Don't post pictures of your code, include actual code and highlight it and press the `{ }` button to format it. Also, what do you expect the function `AddParam` to do? What function do you think it was calling, and show that function.

Comment: If this is for **SQL Server** : `image` data type will be removed in a future version of SQL Server. Avoid using this data types in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use it. Use `varbinary(max)` instead. [See details here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Use this method for converting image into bytes,

```
public byte[] ImageToByte(string imageLocation)
{
    byte[] imageData = null;
    FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(imageLocation);
    long imageFileLength = fileInfo.Length;
    FileStream fs = new FileStream(imageLocation, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
    BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs);
    imageData = br.ReadBytes((int)imageFileLength);
    return imageData;
}
```

Comment: I dont have image location i am not saving it any where i am just turning the selected file into Buytes;

Answer (score 0):

If I had to guess, the method AddParams is calling itself over and over and over again which is why you received a StackOverFlowException:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stackoverflowexception(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: So with what Code do i make it only call it self once i could have multiple Prams too

Comment: I think you may want to take a look at this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters(v=vs.110).aspx

I have a feeling you are trying to create a SqlCommand object. You will want to add your object to the SqlCommand object's property Parameters